# Change color in xaml with converter returning StaticResource Primary

Tags: .net, xaml, maui, ivalueconverter

if I do a converter like this

```
 public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is null)
   
        return "Pink";
   
    else
        return "Red";
}
```

It works properly, but if i want to return a "{StaticResource Primary}" or "StaticResource Primary" instead of Pink ou red it doesn't work

My xaml is like this

```
<Image Source="{FontImageSource FontFamily=MaterialRegular, Glyph={x:Static m:MaterialRegular.Folder}, Color={Binding Action, Converter={StaticResource ConvertColorFolder}}}" />`
```

Do you have any idea to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MAUI some things have changed. Just know you can't directly access Application level Resources it throws exceptions and this is what I use to avoid that:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetResource<T>(this ResourceDictionary dictionary, string key)
    {
        if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out var value) && value is T resource)
            return resource;
        else
            return default;
    }
}
```

Now you need to get the correct Color in your Converter using this extension method (don't forget to add the correct namespace):

```
public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object? parameter, CultureInfo culture)
 {
   var primaryColor = Application.Current.Resources.GetResource<Color>("PrimaryColor");

   if (value is null)
    return primaryColor;
   else
    return Colors.Red;
}
```

Note that this is just an example, and will need changes based on your needs.